# Error in fetch (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'))

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch, backend

**Hello. I run this code and it gives me this error. It seems pretty simple and not difficult. The error refers to the map() method**

```
var div_usuarios = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
var usuarios = [];

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(users=> {
        usuarios = users.data;
        console.log(usuarios);

        usuarios.map((user, i)=>{
            let nombre = document.createElement('h2');
            nombre.innerHTML = i + user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;
            div_usuarios.appendChild(nombre);

        })

    });
```

How can i fix it?

Actually the code is exactly the same from a course I have been following online, but it does not work for me when  I run it!

Comment: `users.data` is `undefined`

Comment: You can just use `users.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the data you're trying to retrieve has changed over time, which may be causing your code to not work as expected. A working example can be found below.

```js
var div_usuarios = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
var usuarios = [];

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(users=> {

        users.map((user, i)=>{
            let nombre = document.createElement('h2');
            nombre.innerHTML = `${user.email} - ${user.name}`;
            div_usuarios.appendChild(nombre);

        })
    });
```

```html
<div id="usuarios">
</div>
```